# How to use Kate text editor for DBMS?

Tags: sql, kate

Has anyone been able to access databases through Kate's SQL plugin? This looks like an excellent alternative to VSCode but I think it requires root access to access db files. I have a database saved in /var/lib/mysql as a file but its not loading up. Any steps to make Kate a good SQL IDE?

Comment: "database saved in /var/lib/mysql as a file but its not loading up"  that is not how this works. You create a CONNECTION using the sql user and pwd that is allowed to be used as an external connection See https://kate-editor.org/2010/07/29/katesql-a-new-plugin-for-kate/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. How do I connect to an existing database in Kate?

Comment: You should use the Kate SQL new connection wizard plugin. It looks like this : https://kate-editor.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/katesql-wizard-screenshot.png. Usually, for a local mySQL, hostname would be 'localhost' and port would be 3306.